# What happened to the last black staff after The Measure of the Magic?

Tags: shannara, terry-brooks

After *The Measure of the Magic* the next book in the Shannara chronological order is *The First King of Shannara*. But in the First King there is no mention of what happened to Panterra Qu and the last black staff. I know it has been a thousand years between the two books, but anyone has any idea of what could have happened do the black staff?

Comment: There is a black staff appearing in the First King of Shannara, which was written quite a bit earlier than Measure of the Magic. It was used by some minor character, a companion of Bremen. I don't remember any details. Probably this was before Terry Brooks decided to merge "the word and the void" with the Shannara world. Iirc before "the word and the void" was written, even.

Answer (score 2):

## No canon information at present

**Out-of-universe**, it may be a gap left intentionally by the author to fill in. The full story of the First Druid council, led by Galaphile, and of Brona's downfall, is yet untold.

**In-universe**, we may only make guesses. It is possible that the magic has evolved and the line of Black Staff Bearers has died out, or evolved into something different.

PS. I have not read *The Fall Of Shannara* books.

Answer (score 1):

In the Elf Queen of Shannara, the Loden stone is affixed to a gnarled polished Black Walnut staff called The Rook Staff.  Imbued with the magic of the elves.
My theory is that at some point before the elves used the Loden to move Aborlan to Morrowindl, they had to locate the last Black Staff of Panterra Qu.  But with all the history lost to even the elves, they are clueless that the bearer of the staff is actually a Knight of The Word.

Comment: The staff holding Loden is different from the Black Staffs, it existed when the Elves relocated to the Four Lands from Our World, simultaneously. It is described in the Genesis trilogy in more detail.